# Is the congruence relations lattice of a lattice a sublattice of all equivalence relations on it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders

By [this Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_algebra#Congruence_lattice), it seem the set of all congruence relaions on a lattice $(X,\le)$ is a complete lattice with inclusion.

Is this lattice a (complete) sublattice of the lattice of all equivalence relations on $X$?

Comment: Yes. You only need to show that the join and meet (as equivalence relations) of two ( or arbitrarily many ) congruences is itself a congruence.

Comment: @Eran Do you know a book in which this is proved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\phi,\psi$ be equivalence relations on a set $X$. It is easy enough to show that the meet of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is $\phi\cap\psi$. Let $\phi\circ\psi=\{(a,b)\in X^2:\text{ there is }c\in X\text{ such that }(a,c)\in\phi \text{ and }(c,b)\in\psi\}.$ It would be nice if $\phi\circ\psi$ were $\psi\vee\psi$, but unfortunately $\phi\circ\psi$ is not transitive (show that it contains $\phi$ and $\psi$, is reflexive, and is symmetric though). However, the transitive closure is the join:
$\phi\vee\psi=\phi\circ\psi\cup\phi\circ\psi\circ\phi\cup\phi\circ\psi\circ\phi\circ\psi\cup\dots$

Now assume $\phi$ and $\psi$ are congruences and show that the meet and join I defined above are also congruences. Also, see if you can guess what the join and meet of an arbitrary collection of equivalence relations is.